# calc function in scss or css is not working

Tags: css, sass, less

Could someone tell me what this line of code is doing in a css file?

`width: calc(100%  - -  -10px)`

the line was originally from a less file. I had the file converted to scss file. The line was unchanged, but not working on the browser after i compiled it.

I checked the docs for calc function, still couldn't figure out what the statement is doing. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like it should be this instead:

```
width: calc(100% -10px)
```

Which sets the width to 100% of its parent, minus 10 pixels.

Comment: Thanks Harley, the css was from the previous developer. the css working fine. so i don't think it's a mistake

Comment: The code would work because it's still a sound mathematical expression. For example 10 - - - 1 is equal to 9. But maybe it was a typo mistake?

Comment: Hi Harley, you are right. it's a typo. I tried calc(100% - 10px) and i got the expected width. I am a backend developer, not very good at css. I thought there's something special in the statement that i'm not familiar with. Thanks for your quick response.